# Can't Find Arduino Drivers Windows 10 Precision3560

Tags: windows-10, drivers, ports, dell-precision, arduino

I'm unable to upload anything to my Arduino Nano because it says it doesn't have the drivers for it.

I've tried going to the Device Manager and going to the USB serial to "update" the drivers but when I point it at the Arduino's driver files it tells me no driver files could be found.

I've tried restarting my computer, reinstalling Arduino and uninstalling the "serial port" all to no avail. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Does the microcontroller show up (the icon) when you try to update the drivers?
Had my fair share of issues like this myself on my laptop for some reason, could not upload to the micro, it randomly disappears not showing up again etc. My solution was to install new USB drivers from intel.

[image]